# GravityForms - calculate two fields into a percentage

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin

Hello stack exchange community,

Is it possible to use the internal gravity forms calculate fields function to calculate it into a percentage? I can't find where in the code this calculation happens so  i can rewrite how the field outputs. Can anyone point me in the correct direction (as in what hook can i use to rewrite how a form field outputs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the "gform_calculation_format_result" JS filter. Copy, paste, and configure the following code in an HTML field on your form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
gform.addFilter( 'gform_calculation_format_result', function(formattedResult, result, formulaField, formId, calcObj ) {
    // UPDATE: "3" to ID of your Calculation field    
    if ( formulaField.field_id == 3 ) {
        formattedResult = gformFormatNumber( result, ! gformIsNumber( formulaField.rounding ) ? -1 : formulaField.rounding, '.', ',' ) + '%';
    }
    return formattedResult;
});
```

Here's an export of a working form if you'd like to import and see this in action ([form export](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/689144/files/gravityforms-export-2016-10-05.json)).